# How to make dynamic find?

Tags: jquery

There is a `dataTable` where each row of a particular column has a dynamic id :

```
{ 
      "aTargets": [3],
      "mData": 3,
      "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            return '<div style="text-align:center;">'+
                                    '<a href="RestaurantCommande/detail/'+ data +'" id="cmd_'+ data +'" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="mif-stack3 mif-2x"></span></a>'+
                                    '<a href="RestaurantCommande/modifier/'+ data +'" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="mif-pencil mif-2x"></span></a>'+
                                    '<span class="mif-cross mif-2x fg-grayLight"></span>'+
                                   '</div>';
}
```

As you can see there is the dynamic id `cmd_`.
Now I want to select a particular id cmd_ on document ready ; the remaining of the id value is a cookie value :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
...
var cookieFromAjoutDetailCommande = Cookies.get('fromAjoutModifDetailsCommande');
if (cookieFromAjoutDetailCommande != null) {
     var _id = "cmd_"+cookieFromAjoutDetailCommande;
     $('#list_commandes').find("a[id='']").click(); // here I want to write the dynamic id
}
...
});

</script>
```

So how to select this particular element ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#list_commandes').find("#"+ _id).click();
```

And since it's an id, I assume they are unique, you can just go with:

```
$("#"+ _id).click();
```

Comment: the click event is not triggered ! the element is a link so jquery needs a get , so how to write correctly ?

Comment: if you generate the element via code / ajax / whatever, you have to register the click event via delegate..

Comment: @pheromix it doesn't matter the element is link or a any thing, as long as you have the correct id it should work. Make sure that you have correct id in `"cmd_"+cookieFromAjoutDetailCommande`, check if that exists in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way, while adding anchor to div take `onclick` event and call a function from that event, something like this.

```
{ 
      "aTargets": [3],
      "mData": 3,
      "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            return '<div style="text-align:center;">'+
                                    '<a href="RestaurantCommande/detail/'+ data +'" id="cmd_'+ data +'" style="margin-right: 8px;" onclick="test()"><span class="mif-stack3 mif-2x"></span></a>'+
                                    '<a href="RestaurantCommande/modifier/'+ data +'" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="mif-pencil mif-2x"></span></a>'+
                                    '<span class="mif-cross mif-2x fg-grayLight"></span>'+
                                   '</div>';
}
```

and then define a `test` method in JS

```
function test()
{
//do something
}
```

Check the js fiddle for a working example

**Fiddle:** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uebkdfuz/)

Comment: the click event is not triggered ! the element is a link so jquery needs a get , so how to write correctly ?

Comment: @pheromix : check the updated answer with fiddle for a good idea.